# listview on click to edit

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have set up a listview with one edit text widget. The listview is populated with a string file and I wanted to make changes on each item by clicking on the item. code builds and the listview shows as planned. When the item is clicked it gets focus but then looses focus after the keyboard pops up without any entries.

els_edit_tiles.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/listText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >
</EditText>
```

This is the onclicklistener, I assume the changes will need to be here and did not post the adapter code.

```
   private class ListClickhandler implements OnItemClickListener {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> Adapter, View view, int position, long arg3) {

        TextView listText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        String text = listText.getText().toString();
        // Toast.makeText(context, text + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of having an edit text widget on the list view, try to have a dialog pop up on item click and then put the edit text on that dialog. Save the text when user pressed okay.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the item loses its highlight, rather than focus.  Focus goes wherever you tap and is there whether the highlight shows or not.  So, I'll explain some options for the disappearing highlight.

For better or worse, they've designed it this way.  You have a few choices.  One is to subclass ListView and try to figure out how to add a sticky highlight.  (I tried that and got it to work, but abandoned it for another reason - I wanted to put the list in a ScrollView, which doesn't work with a ListView).

Another choice: use a spinner (aka a drop down list).  This doesn't exactly do what you're asking but it does show you which item was selected -- it is the one that shows when the spinner collapses.

Yet a third choice (I implemented this) - Use a LinearLayout and add each item as a child of the layout.  You have to implement your own selection and highlighting, but that takes relatively little code (I can help if you need).  This effectively gives you a list that shows all items - it doesn't scroll.  You can include it in a ScrollView along with other elements to scroll the whole collection together.

Comment: In this case the listview is only 8 items. I started with 8 edit text widgets but I wanted to be flexible as I may add some i-cons to the listview as my knowledge of Android is expanded. You are correct on highlight the position tag for edit shows then disappears  when keyboard pops up.